# Discord.js: How to set a custom status for my bot when using an advanced event handler?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was wondering if anyone would know how I can set a custom status for my bot when I have this advanced event handler. My current coding does not seem to work, so let me know if I can change anything.

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
    const load_dir = (dirs) => {
        const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./Natsuki Events/${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for (const file of eventFiles) {
            const event = require(`../Natsuki Events/${dirs}/${file}`);
            const eventName = file.split('.')[0];
            client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, Discord, client), () => {
                client.user.setActivity("a game with That Penguin Guy", { type: 'PLAYING' });
            })
        }
    }

    ['Client', 'Guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e));
}
```

I also have an file for the "ready" event so let me know if I need to stick anything there instead:

```
module.exports = () => {
    console.log('Natsuki is online!');
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason the activity has to be set there (on every event?), rather than just setting the activity once, during the "ready" event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are sending "client" as parameter from event handler and then you must take it from ready event file. Your ready event file should be like that:

```
module.exports = (client) => {
    console.log('Natsuki is online!');
    client.user.setActivity('my status', { type: 'PLAYING' })
}
```

You can pick one of these types from https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ActivityType

Comment: This is the exact thing I thought I needed to do, but it would not work, so when I went to try the other bit of coding I used for this example. After that not working, I resorted to using this website to gain some help.